# Custom sequence generator - PLSQL

Tags: sql, plsql

I am trying to get sequence number from the following Plsql package and update the row of given contractObjId. I have a java program to invoke this in threading environment.

Multiple threads can invoke at the same time and having same contractobjId. My issue is that it is generating the duplicate sequence numbers when multiple threads are invoking.

please suggest the solution and point out where i am doing wrong.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY MANAGE_SEQ_NO IS
  PROCEDURE GET_NEXT_SEQ_NUM (contractobjid NUMBER, seqCur IN OUT SITECURTYP) IS
       seq_no NUMBER;
       seq_value NUMBER;
  BEGIN
     SELECT x_sequence_no 
     INTO seq_no 
     FROM table_contract 
     WHERE objid = contractObjid 
     FOR     UPDATE;
     IF seq_no IS NULL THEN
        seq_value := 1;
     ELSE
         seq_value := seq_no+1;
     END IF;
     UPDATE table_contract 
     SET x_sequence_no = seq_value 
     WHERE objid = contractObjid;
     COMMIT;
     OPEN seqCur FOR
     SELECT seq_value FROM dual;
  END GET_NEXT_SEQ_NUM;
END;
/
```

Comment: Why not use a **real** sequence. That's what they are for. Doing your own sequences is either awfully slow and will not scale or it won't be correct (as in your case).

Comment: It is needed for every row i mean for every contractObjID. We are inserting intially 0 and using procedure to increment. I think, we have write sequence dynamically whenevr we insert a row which is not possible.

Comment: @Mahesh: Yes it is, put a before insert trigger on the table which selects the nextval from the sequence and puts it in the appropriate column.

Comment: @SteveG: Can you please put your idea with embedded your code snippet in above code?

Comment: Start with updating sequence , this will block other threads

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you don't want to use a real sequence, you can probably use `SELECT FOR UPDATE`. This'll lock the line you are reading, you can increase whatever, and then do the update. Of course, it'll lock the line and depending on what you do it could create some scalability problems.

Comment: I am using Select for update in my current code. It is not working as it locks row and prevents any updates for that row. But, in my case any oter thread come and select the query and update same value. i.e. 2 threads are updating same value which is wrong.

Comment: So you have no choice: if you want to update the same value, but respect the order, you have to lock the row. Or you don't put any lock, and you just use Oracle's sequences

Comment: Can we use table lock concept to lock on select statement. I was googling and found this but i am not sure. Select for update is preventing only update but not selection.

Comment: You don't put any code. I can't tell you anything. Just try, it's a database, as long as you don't commit you can always rollback. Nothing bad can happen

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY MANAGE_SEQ_NO IS
    PROCEDURE GET_NEXT_SEQ_NUM (contractobjid NUMBER, seqCur IN OUT    SITECURTYP) IS
   seq_no NUMBER;
     seq_value NUMBER;
 BEGIN
 SELECT x_sequence_no INTO seq_no FROM table_contract WHERE objid = contractObjid FOR     UPDATE;
 IF seq_no IS NULL THEN
    seq_value := 1;
 ELSE
     seq_value := seq_no+1;
 END IF;
 UPDATE table_contract SET x_sequence_no = seq_value WHERE objid = contractObjid;
 COMMIT;
 OPEN seqCur FOR
 SELECT seq_value FROM dual;
 END GET_NEXT_SEQ_NUM;
END;
/

Comment: You can create your own lock using the DBMS_LOCK package.  Of course,  scalability will be killed.

Answer (score 1):

> "Can we use table lock concept to lock on select statement."

No.  Nothing blocks readers in Oracle.